# Buttons' shaders are cutted off using a flutter plug-in

Tags: flutter, dart, button, plugins

**I created some buttons for my flutter app menu and then I tried to give them some clicky animations.
I found a plug-in that was meant for me, so I edited the code from it but I got some problems.**

*As you can see from the images below, the buttons' shadows are cutted off, and I don't know how to fix them.
(I just need to know how to solve this little issue)*

That’s the plug-in I edited:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  final Widget child;
  final bool enabled;
  final double padding;
  final bool isCircular;
  final Color color;
  final Color shadowColor;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final ShadowDegree shadowDegree;
  final int duration;

  const AnimatedButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.onPressed,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.isCircular,
    this.padding = 0.0,
    this.enabled = true,
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    this.shadowColor = Colors.blueAccent,
    this.height = 64,
    this.shadowDegree = ShadowDegree.light,
    this.width = 200,
    this.duration = 70,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedButtonState createState() => _AnimatedButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedButtonState extends State<AnimatedButton> {

  static const Curve _curve = Curves.easeIn;
  static const double _shadowHeight = 4;
  double _position = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double _height = widget.height - _shadowHeight;
    return GestureDetector(
      // width here is required for centering the button in parent
        child: Container(
            width: widget.width,
            height: _height + _shadowHeight,
            child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[

                  // Shadow
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: -8,
                    child: Container(
                      height: _height,
                      width: widget.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: widget.enabled
                            ? widget.shadowColor
                            : darken(Colors.grey, widget.shadowDegree),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          widget.isCircular ? Radius.circular(37) : Radius.circular(30)
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ),

                  // Button
                  AnimatedPositioned(
                      curve: _curve,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.duration),
                      bottom: _position,
                      child: Container(
                          height: _height,
                          width: widget.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: widget.enabled ? widget.color : Colors.grey,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  widget.isCircular ? Radius.circular(37) : Radius.circular(27)
                              )
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: widget.padding),
                            child: Center(
                                child: widget.child
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                  )

                ]
            )
        ),
        onTapDown: widget.enabled ? _pressed : null,
        onTapUp: widget.enabled ? _unPressedOnTapUp : null,
        onTapCancel: widget.enabled ? _unPressed : null
    );
  }

  void _pressed(_) {
    setState(() {
      _position = -4;
    });
  }

  void _unPressedOnTapUp(_) => _unPressed();

  // top
  void _unPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _position = 4;
    });
    widget.onPressed();
  }
}

Color darken(Color color, ShadowDegree degree) {
  double amount = degree == ShadowDegree.dark ? 0.5 : 0.12;
  final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  final hslDark = hsl.withLightness((hsl.lightness + amount).clamp(0.0, 1.0));

  return hslDark.toColor();
}

enum ShadowDegree { light, dark }
```

And that is how a button is made:

```
AnimatedButton(
            color: Color(0xff4388fc),
            child: Text(
              "LOCAL",
              style: TextStyles().textStyleMenuButtonText()
            ),
            height: 80,
            width: 250,
            shadowColor: Color(0xff2963d4),
            isCircular: false,
            padding: 6.0,
            onPressed: () {
              ModeSelectorDialog().getDialog(
                  context,
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
              );
            }
          ),
```

*images*

[I got 5 buttons, but their shadows are cutted off, and I don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z0rQ.png)

[That's how I want them to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsLku.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the default constructor of a Stack by setting the overflow

```
overflow: Overflow.visible
```

Your build method of the animated button should look like this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double _height = widget.height - _shadowHeight;
    return GestureDetector(
        // width here is required for centering the button in parent
        child: Container(
            width: widget.width,
            height: _height + _shadowHeight,
            child: Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible, children: <Widget>[
              // Shadow
              Positioned(
                  bottom: -8,
                  child: Container(
                      height: _height,
                      width: widget.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: widget.enabled
                              ? widget.shadowColor
                              : darken(Colors.grey, widget.shadowDegree),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(widget.isCircular
                              ? Radius.circular(37)
                              : Radius.circular(30))))),

              // Button
              AnimatedPositioned(
                  curve: _curve,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.duration),
                  bottom: _position,
                  child: Container(
                      height: _height,
                      width: widget.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: widget.enabled ? widget.color : Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(widget.isCircular
                              ? Radius.circular(37)
                              : Radius.circular(27))),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: widget.padding),
                        child: Center(child: widget.child),
                      )))
            ])),
        onTapDown: widget.enabled ? _pressed : null,
        onTapUp: widget.enabled ? _unPressedOnTapUp : null,
        onTapCancel: widget.enabled ? _unPressed : null);
  }
```